# Enable virtual machine auto startup in ESXi 6.0

Tags: esxi

I have an ESXi 6.0 server with two VMs, using VSphere 6.0 with the desktop client to manage them.  When I power on the server, the VMs still have to be started manually.  Is there a way so that they automatically start up?  Strangely, I could not find any setting to allow that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup the VMs startup policy on ESXi host in Configuration -> Virtual Machine Startup and Shutdown -> Properties menu. In the window that pops up, check Allow virtual machines to start and stop automatically with the system to enable the option, choose the stop-action as Guest Shutdown. Click Ok to proceed.
Hope that helps

Comment: I'm sorry, but where is that "Configuration" tab **in the vSpehere desktop client**. I can't seem to find it.

Comment: https://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2013/05_w21/655994/Click-Configuration-Tab.jpg